# Browser cannot find CSS image path

Tags: css, image

I have used an image file located on my PC by CSS `background-image: URL(img/bg.png);` But the browser tries to get the image from `css/img/bg.png`. How to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's an exact way you can fix this problem, it's most likely you have a directory called css and in there there is another directory called img where your background image is stored. I don't exactly understand what you're asking for. The problem you have should be taking place in your directories.

Comment: I have a directory `css`. And another directory `img`. I can fix the directory problem by using the complete directory. But I have to transfer my product to my teammates. Their root directory is different from mine. It will cause problems.

Comment: Without more information on your project structure and server configuration we'd fish in muddy waters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try `background-image: URL(../img/bg.png)` ?

The `..` will look for the image one directory up.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem.